# How to access a docker container from another machine than its windows host?

Tags: networking, docker

I Am able to run tomcat and deployed my war file.
And I am able to run the app/rest web service via http://192.168.99.100:8887/RestServ/rest/hello/text.

However, when I hit the above URL in some other machine, it returns nothing/blank.

I understand 192.168.99.100 is a private IP, but how I can run my application from ‘anywhere’?

Answer (score 0):

> how I can run my application from ‘anywhere’

You would need to:

- use the public IP or your Windows or Mac host
- make sure the port 8887 is accessible (for instance, by [allowing traffic in the Windows firewall for that port](https://superuser.com/a/144543/141))

Those steps are not specific to docker.